# Is it posible to change the template of the "Unhandled Exception" error page in .NET?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net

Our client wants to be able to redesign the page which displays an "Unhandled Exception".

We're using Visual Studio 2012 with C#.NET (ASPX).

Is this possible to do?

Edit: Thanks for the downvotes. Care to explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Microsoft: [Displaying a Custom Error Page (C#)](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs):

> When an unhandled exception arises in an ASP.NET application one of
>   three types of error pages is displayed:
>
> - The Exception Details Yellow Screen of Death error page,
> - The Runtime Error Yellow Screen of Death error page, or
> - A custom error page

Short version:

- Create a custom web page in your ASP.NET web app.
- Add customErrors markup to the `configuration` -> `system.web` section of your application's **web.config** file:

  ```
  <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"
                    defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPages/Oops.aspx" />
  </system.web>
  ```

See the above link for additional information on how to do it, as well as how to add custom pages for individual HTTP status codes, etc.